# Как добавлять атрибут required только выбраной радиокнопке?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

```html
     <input id="b_1" type="radio" checked  required class="input" name="place">
     <input id="b_2" type="radio" class="input" name="place">
```

Comment: Нафига? Если она выбрана - она точно уже отправится, и `required` тут просто не влияет ни на что...

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar, для валидации https://jsfiddle.net/owb80f73/1/

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1369717/191482   --- тут в комментарии на писали что в вопросе нет чекбоксов))

Comment: @olenafront Выглядит как костыль... Не проще самим js и обрабатывать?

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar, так через js и буду обрабатывать. Просто главное атрибут requored менять

Comment: @olenafront Зачем? Вы можете через `e.preventDefault();` останавливать отправку и делать что угодно

Comment: не так все просто .. вот типа такое нужно, только сделанное на jqueryvalidate - jsfiddle.net/ozug5sew –

Answer (score 1):

Атрибут required не имеет смысл менять, он будет работать для всех `input type="radio"` с одинаковым `name` атрибутом

```html
<form>
  <input id="b_1" type="radio" class="input" name="place" value="1" required>
  <input id="b_2" type="radio" class="input" name="place" value="2">
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: для валидации, как я поняла не в required дело https://jsfiddle.net/owb80f73/3/

Comment: @olenafront не понимаю, у меня же работает валидация, при нажатии на кнопку Отправить не отправляется, если я не выбрал какое-то поле

Comment: вот типа такое нужно, только сделанное на jqueryvalidate - https://jsfiddle.net/ozug5sew/

Comment: @olenafront ну тут форма вообще не отправляется ни в каком случае. Вы хотите не отправлять форму в любом случае?

Comment: @olenafront объясните вашу задачу и вопрос чётче и яснее, тогда я и другие смогут понять и ответить на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно зачем..вы про это ?

```js
$('input[type=radio]').click(function(e){
  $('input[type=radio]').prop('required',false);
  $(this).prop('required',true);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="b_1" type="radio" checked  required class="input" name="place">
<input id="b_2" type="radio" class="input" name="place">
```

Comment: для валидации, как я поняла не в required дело https://jsfiddle.net/owb80f73/3/

Comment: вот типа такое нужно, только сделанное на jqueryvalidate - https://jsfiddle.net/ozug5sew/

Comment: @olenafront просто выкиньте этот плагин и напишите свою валидацию. Экономия нервов и времени

Comment: требуют с ним..

Comment: @olenafront Сделал вам решение в рамках предыдущей темы. Смотрите там.